# Limit the angle of the rotation motors

Tags: python, nodes, robotics, webots

is it possible to limit the rotation motors of an industrial robot (IRB4600/40) in WeBots?
As an example: the motor should no longer have a freedom of 2 Pi in both directions, but only 1 Pi each.

I need this for a reinforcement learning task that I want to carry out with WeBots. However, I would like to be able to limit the space in which actions are performed.

An idea for this: I could specify maximum/minimum positions at which the robot stops learning.
However, this is a solution that I am not satisfied with.

Therefore the question: Is there a WeBots node with which I can limit the rotation angle of motors?

Many Thanks
Moritz

Answer (score 1):

You can set a value to `minPosition` and `maxPosition` for each `RotationalMotor` node. See the documentation [here](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/motor). If you want to do this for a robot that is defined in a proto file, you will have to edit the corresponding proto file accordingly.